# How to make http2 request with react native?

Tags: react-native, apple-push-notifications, http2

I have following curl request which works perfectly with my terminal,

```
curl -v \
-d '{"aps":{"alert":"Test","badge":42,”uuid”:”testuuid”}, "data": {"Username": "Alex", "ConnectionId": "Alex123”,”uuid”:”testuuid”},”uuid”:”testuuid”}’ \
-H "apns-push-type: voip" \
-H "apns-priority: 10" \
--http2 \
--cert voip.pem \
https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/c91119f600ccea97348b479e9648b3e29d12fae018a92da82bea6c18bba
```

This makes a **http2** request to apple push notifications service.

Now I want to use it from my react native codebase. I wonder whether axios or fetch apis support making a http2 request.(I searched and couldn't find an answer) I found [this](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) library but seems there is no way to pass my certificate.
How can I acheive my requirement using react native ?